# Where do apps live?

Tags: google-play, app-store

This is a naive question. I'm creating my first app (using Phonegap). I'll create versions in both the App Store and Google Play Store. My question is:  **where will the downloadable files live?**

I haven't been able to find the answer online, because I'm not sure how to phrase the question in a simple Google search. I've thought of 2 possibilities:

1. The downloadable files live on my server. When someone chooses to install the app from the App Store or the Google Play Store, that store authorizes the download **from** my server.
2. The downloadable file lives on the App Store's servers or the Google Play Store servers. When someone chooses to download it, the file is served directly by them.

I'm almost sure the answer is #2.  That makes the most sense.  But I haven't found confirmation online.

Comment: you have to upload your binary to google's server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to host it on your server or  use services provided by Google and Apple.

Hosting on your server will require you to maintain those servers , etc.. Hosting with Google & Apple will take away that maintenance.

Use **Google Expansion Files** for Google Play Store App and **Content Hosting** for Apple

1. Google Allow APK size of **100 MB** any additional files can be uploaded using Expansion files. Refer to this link - https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html
2. Maximum file size for an IPA file is **2 GB** in Apple. If you are using Apple's in-app purchase module , then you can upload additional files using Content Hosting given by apple. Refer to this link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html

Comment: So I was _mostly_ right, but I needed some more details. Thanks for providing them!

Comment: For iOS apps, the binary executable code, and any data files bundled with the binary executable, can only be hosted on Apple's iTunes servers.  Apps have to be able to run (not crash) even if no other servers can be contacted.